# GDB disassembling does not recognize ASM lables e.g: _start

Tags: assembly, gdb, reverse-engineering

i have an assembly file that i assembled and linked with this commands:

```sh
$ nasm -f elf -F dwarf -g -o FILENAME.o FILENAME.asm
$ ld -o FILENAME FILENAME.o
```

As you can see i have added `-g` so nasm generates debugging symbols. and the file format is like this:

```
section .code:
global _start
_start:
      ASM HERE
ANOTHER_LABEL:
      ASM HERE
YET_ANOTHER_LABEL:
      ASM HERE
```

when i launch `gdb -q FILENAME` and after running the file (`run`), i try to disassemble `_start` via `disassemble _start` it gives me this error:

`'_start' has unknown type; cast it to its declared type`
it gives me the same erroe (`_start` changes) when i try to disassemble any other label name (`ANOTHER_LABEL` or `YET_ANOTHER_LABEL`).
Also when i type only `disassemble` it only gives me the disassembly of the first label ( from `_start` to the beginning of `ANOTHER_LABEL`).
How do i fix this error?

Comment: You should set the type and the size of the functions. Easier to do something like `x/10i _start`

Comment: @Jester it gives me the same error : `'_start' has unknown type; cast it to its declared type`

Comment: Also you should use `section .text` not `section .code`. That is known to confuse gdb :)

Comment: @Jester thank you i just noticed it and fixed it, but still it didn't fix it, i don't know what is going wrong with gdb

Comment: @Jester i do however make my own way in disassembling it, but i do want to use this particular command ( i see it quit a lot in tutos e.g: `disass main`) but gdb does not like it.

Comment: Also only `disassemble` that has this problem using : `info line _start` gives me the starting address.

Comment: Without size information disassemble only works up to the next symbol. gdb doesn't know the limit of the function. I don't think nasm even supports putting size info into the object file.

Comment: @Jester i don't know what is going wrong with it, i follow the same steps on online tutos, when he/she tries `disass LABEL_NAME` it just work for them, but in my case it gives that error.

Comment: I don't get the error either. You don't have any `.gdbinit` customizations, right?

Comment: @Jester thank you for testing it out, i do have some custom lines in my `.gdbinit`, i will remove them and see.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old but i just had the same problem and found the solution:

Eliminate the 'SECTION' tag from .code and it should work, for me it does.

Comment: With NASM?  `.code` on a line by itself is treated as a label, like `.code:`, with the warning `warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error`.  You should remove the line entirely, or change to `section .text` if you actually want to switch sections to the one that machine code belongs in.